# how to solve my errors in my code about online test to be like in the pdf file?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OnlineTest {

public static void entry() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please, Enter Your  Full Name :");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please, Enter your Test Registration ID :");
    double id = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println(" . . . Starting Test\n");

    test(double score1, double score2, double score3);

}

public static void test(double score1, double score2, double score3) {
    String answer;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("- Choose the Correct Answer:\n");

    do {
    System.out.println("a. Which Utility is used to compile Java applications?\n"
            + "   1. javaw\n"
            + "   2. java\n"
            + "   3. javac " );
    answer = input.next();
    }while(!answer.equals("1") && !answer.equals("2") && !answer.equals("3"));

    if(answer.equals("3") ) {
       score1 = 100;
    }else if (!answer.equals("3")) {
       score1 = 0;
    }

    do {
        System.out.println("b. Which is a restriction when using a switch statement? \n"
                + "   1. Characters cannot be used\n"
                + "   2. Doubles cannot be used\n"
                + "   3. Integers can not be used" );
        answer = input.next();
        }while(!answer.equals("1") && !answer.equals("2") && !answer.equals("3"));

        if(answer.equals("1") ) {
           score2 = 100;
        }else if (!answer.equals("1")) {
           score2 = 0;
        }

        do {
            System.out.println("c. What is the range of byte data type in Java?  \n"
                    + "   1. -128 to 127\n"
                    + "   2. -32768 to 32767\n"
                    + "   3. -2147483648 to 2147483647" );
            answer = input.next();
            }while(!answer.equals("1") && !answer.equals("2") && !answer.equals("3"));

            if(answer.equals("1") ) {
               score3 = 100;
            }else if (!answer.equals("1")) {
                 score3 = 0;
            }

            double totalscores = score1 + score2 + score3;

}

public static void results(double totalscores) {

    double percentage = totalscores ;
    printData(percentage);
}

public static void printData(double percentage) {

    System.out.println("-----------------------");

    System.out.println("\tJava Certification\n"
              + "\t   Test Results\n");

    System.out.println("Name : "  );



    System.out.println("Passing Score 52% ");
    System.out.println("Your Score : " + percentage + "% \n");


    System.out.println("Max Score --------------------100%\r\n" + 
                "Passing Score -----------52");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    entry();
    printData(double percentage);
}

}
```

[important file final project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2jJ6WgvkYaeTmlwV0tLNXc2RjA5T1JLSjZZRHBLMTVndi1B)

How can I solve it about online test to be like in the pdf file?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: change `test(double score1, double score2, double score3);` to 
    `test(score1, score2, score3);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Hi!This is your code without errors!

So, I changed somethings, I'll list them to get clearer.

1. To use "Name" and "Id" in more than one method, it is easier if they are global variables.
2. When calling the "test" method you need to pass the values, so in the "entry" method the values are passed.
3. The "printData" method is called within "results" to receive the value of "totalScores"
4. Also in the "results" method to calculate the value of "percentage" you must divide by the number of scores, which in this case is 3
5. The methods need to be static, just the test method. In the test method, a class must be instantiated to test the class itself.

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class OnlineTest {       
   String name;
   double id;

   public void entry() {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Please, Enter Your  Full Name :");
       name = input.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Please, Enter your Test Registration ID :");
       id = input.nextDouble();

       System.out.println(" . . . Starting Test\n");

       test(0, 0, 0);
   }

   public void test(double score1, double score2, double score3) {
       String answer;
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("- Choose the Correct Answer:\n");

       do {
           System.out.println("a. Which Utility is used to compile Java applications?\n" + "   1. javaw\n"
                   + "   2. java\n" + "   3. javac ");
           answer = input.next();
       } while (!answer.equals("1") && !answer.equals("2") && !answer.equals("3"));

       if (answer.equals("3")) {
           score1 = 100;
       } else if (!answer.equals("3")) {
           score1 = 0;
       }

       do {
           System.out.println(
                   "b. Which is a restriction when using a switch statement? \n" + "   1. Characters cannot be used\n"
                           + "   2. Doubles cannot be used\n" + "   3. Integers can not be used");
           answer = input.next();
       } while (!answer.equals("1") && !answer.equals("2") && !answer.equals("3"));

       if (answer.equals("1")) {
           score2 = 100;
       } else if (!answer.equals("1")) {
           score2 = 0;
       }

       do {
           System.out.println("c. What is the range of byte data type in Java?  \n" + "   1. -128 to 127\n"
                   + "   2. -32768 to 32767\n" + "   3. -2147483648 to 2147483647");
           answer = input.next();
       } while (!answer.equals("1") && !answer.equals("2") && !answer.equals("3"));

       if (answer.equals("1")) {
           score3 = 100;
       } else if (!answer.equals("1")) {
           score3 = 0;
       }

       double totalscores = score1 + score2 + score3;
       results(totalscores);

   }

   public void results(double totalscores) {

       double percentage = (totalscores) / 3;
       printData(percentage);
   }

   public void printData(double percentage) {

       System.out.println("-----------------------");

       System.out.println("\tJava Certification\n" + "\t   Test Results\n");

       System.out.println("Name : " + name);
       System.out.println("Test Registration ID:" + id);

       System.out.println("Passing Score 52% ");
       System.out.println("Your Score : " + percentage + "% \n");

       System.out.println("Max Score --------------------100%\r\n" + "Passing Score -----------52");

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       OnlineTest onlineTest = new OnlineTest();
       onlineTest.entry();

   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Some questions are of such low quality that they shouldn't be answered, and this is one Why?  Because you'll encourage more homework dumps from the original poster. Please keep this in mind for future questions that you might answer.

Comment: thnx alot but did u see the pdf file